# Woocommerce products show outdated images

Tags: wordpress

I have recently updated the Woocommerce theme and now the products show outdated images, used one year ago, instead of the new ones. I check the products description and the image is right, it's only on the website that the old images show. I cleared the cache on wordpress as well as on my computer's browser's. I also checked from a different computer and it still shows the outdated images. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It was sorted out. I removed removed the old images and deleted the cache.. it was a flaw in woocommerce